# Match pair of numbers against dictionary containing pairs of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Using Python 3.9, but can upgrade to newer)

I have two numbers - CPU (in vCPU) and RAM (in GB) - the resource requirements of an application.

From a list of instance sizes, I am trying to find the closest match that my application can run on - as long as the instance has enough CPU and RAM.

Here is the specific list of instances I want to compare against:

```py
instance_sizes = [
    {"name": "t3a.nano", "cpu": 2, "mem": 0.5},
    {"name": "t3a.micro", "cpu": 2, "mem": 1},
    {"name": "t3a.small", "cpu": 2, "mem": 2},
    {"name": "t3a.medium/c5a.large", "cpu": 2, "mem": 4},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.large", "cpu": 2, "mem": 8},
    {"name": "c5a.xlarge", "cpu": 4, "mem": 8},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.xlarge", "cpu": 4, "mem": 16},
    {"name": "c5a.2xlarge", "cpu": 8, "mem": 16},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.2xlarge", "cpu": 8, "mem": 32},
]
```

- `cpu` 1.8, `mem` 6 should return `t3a/m5a.large`

  - (this has 2 vCPU, and 8GB RAM. the `t3a.small` doesn't have enough RAM with only 4GB)
- `cpu` 0.1, `mem` 6 should return `t3a/m5a.large`

  - (this has 2 vCPU, and 8GB RAM. the `t3a.small` doesn't have enough RAM with only 4GB. it's still oversized, e.g. 0.1 CPU to 2, but it's the smallest instance capable of running the application)
- `cpu` 2.1, `mem` 6 should return `c5a.xlarge`
- `cpu` 6, `mem` 16 should return `c5a.2xlarge`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option, with a test to demonstrate that it passes all your examples:

```
import pytest

instance_sizes = [
    {"name": "t3a.nano", "cpu": 2, "mem": 0.5},
    {"name": "t3a.micro", "cpu": 2, "mem": 1},
    {"name": "t3a.small", "cpu": 2, "mem": 2},
    {"name": "t3a.medium/c5a.large", "cpu": 2, "mem": 4},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.large", "cpu": 2, "mem": 8},
    {"name": "c5a.xlarge", "cpu": 4, "mem": 8},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.xlarge", "cpu": 4, "mem": 16},
    {"name": "c5a.2xlarge", "cpu": 8, "mem": 16},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.2xlarge", "cpu": 8, "mem": 32},
]


def get_instance_size(cpu, mem):
    return next(
        x
        for x in sorted(instance_sizes, key=lambda size: size["cpu"])
        if x["cpu"] >= cpu and x["mem"] >= mem
    )


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "cpu,mem,expected",
    (
        (1.8, 6, "t3a/m5a.large"),
        (0.1, 6, "t3a/m5a.large"),
        (2.1, 6, "c5a.xlarge"),
        (6, 16, "c5a.2xlarge"),
    ),
)
def test_get_instance_size(cpu, mem, expected):
    res = get_instance_size(cpu, mem)

    assert res is not None
    assert res["name"] == expected
```

Running pytest against the above code results in:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.3.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
collecting ... collected 4 items

flavors.py::test_get_instance_size[1.8-6-t3a/m5a.large] PASSED           [ 25%]
flavors.py::test_get_instance_size[0.1-6-t3a/m5a.large] PASSED           [ 50%]
flavors.py::test_get_instance_size[2.1-6-c5a.xlarge] PASSED              [ 75%]
flavors.py::test_get_instance_size[6-16-c5a.2xlarge] PASSED              [100%]

============================== 4 passed in 0.01s ===============================
```

In the above code, `get_instance_size` will raise a `StopIteration` exception if it can't find a match.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have sorted the list of dictionary objects, which can be done in-place with:

```py
instance_sizes.sort(key=lambda x: (x["cpu"], x["mem"]))
```

Then you can define a method that iterates through the list and compare both the cpu and the mem options. The use of binary search and others could work as well (and may be faster but if you are only using a small list, the performance is negligible).

```py
def get_next_largest_instance_size(cpu, mem):
  for instance in instance_sizes:
    if (instance["cpu"] >= cpu and instance["mem"] >= mem):
      return instance
    # raise exception if not found
```

Answer (score -1):

Take advantage of the fact that instance_sizes is already sorted. All you have to do is iterate over that, and return the first acceptable match.

I recognize the data set, so I know it's finite and we don't care about big-O. Sometimes the simplest solution is the best. If you needed to sort, I assume you'd just add price to each record in instance_sizes. (But only sort when the instance metadata changes. If there are many calls to lookup, we don't want that overhead).

```
instance_sizes = [
    {"name": "t3a.nano", "cpu": 2, "mem": 0.5},
    {"name": "t3a.micro", "cpu": 2, "mem": 1},
    {"name": "t3a.small", "cpu": 2, "mem": 2},
    {"name": "t3a.medium/c5a.large", "cpu": 2, "mem": 4},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.large", "cpu": 2, "mem": 8},
    {"name": "c5a.xlarge", "cpu": 4, "mem": 8},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.xlarge", "cpu": 4, "mem": 16},
    {"name": "c5a.2xlarge", "cpu": 8, "mem": 16},
    {"name": "t3a/m5a.2xlarge", "cpu": 8, "mem": 32},
]


def lookup(cpu, mem):
    for instance in instance_sizes:
        if instance['cpu'] > cpu and instance['mem'] > mem:
            return instance['name']
    return None

print(lookup(1.8, 6))
print(lookup(0.1, 6))
print(lookup(2.1, 6))
print(lookup(6, 16))
```

> t3a/m5a.large
> t3a/m5a.large
> c5a.xlarge
> t3a/m5a.2xlarge